# How to implement explicit light sampling when implementing path tracing?

Tags: pathtracing

I implemented a [path tracer](https://github.com/zwcloud/CSharpPathTracer) and got a similar result like [this one](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/is-it-expected-that-a-naive-path-tracer-takes-many-many-samples-to-converge).

Sample: 4096, time used: 537.05s
[image]

The algorithm is exactly the same as [the one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing#Algorithm) in wikipedia, where only the **Gathering Path** is considered.

In [this answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/3976/7114), @Nathan Reed said that "Without explicit light sampling, I'd expect very slow convergence.".

What is *explicit light sampling*? How to implement it? Do it mean *Shooting rays* from [bidirectional path tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing#Bidirectional_path_tracing), namely the **Shooting Path**?

Nathan Reed also said that "Naive path tracing is more reasonable with e.g. a sky light, which almost every path can be expected to hit." So, BTW, what is a sky light? How to implement it?

Comment: Explicit light sampling aka Next Event Estimation. Basically at each bounce you shoot a ray towards light source and 1 ray elsewhere to compute direct and indirect illumination separately. Richie provided a very good answer here
https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/progressive-path-tracing-with-explicit-light-sampling?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @gallickgunner I didn't read the thread you linked in detail but what got my attention was that the advice on MIS is bad, if not outright wrong.
Also zwcloud: yes you can regard direct light sampling as an estimator from BDPT (in fact it is, an estimator with k bounces from the camera with a direct connection).